# Initialize phpmyadmin login fields with server and username?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a `phpmyadmin` instance that allows `AllowArbitraryServer=true`.

Question: is it possible to create `GET` bookmarks for the browser, so that the server + username is prefilled? Like:

`http://localhost/phpmyadmin?pma_host=targethost&pma_username=root`